# Restrict access to a folder installed using wix installer

Tags: wix, installation

My use case is to run a msi package which creates a folder, in addition to doing other things, which should be accessible only to the Administrators. I tried using the util:PermissionEx element but the wix page for the PermissionEx element doesn’t really tell about what do different attributes do. I tried various things, one eg below, but I was still able to access the created folder from both administrator and a non-admin user account.

```
<Directory Id=“TmpDir” Name=“TmpDir”>

<Component Id="CreateDir" Guid=“<>">

    <CreateFolder>

      <util:PermissionEx User="Users" Read="no" GenericRead="no”/> <!— Tried different combinations here —>

    </CreateFolder>

  </Component>

  </Directory>
```

Any help as to what should I do to achieve what I have stated above. Let me know if my question is unclear and I can explain in a more detail or in a different way. Also the Package has

```
InstallScope="perMachine"
InstallPrivileges="elevated"
```

Comment: @AlexeySemenyuk if I am not wrong those threads talk about giving some sort of permissions to the user. What I want is to restrict permission for a folder from a set of users. I wasn't able to find it in those threads and in many other threads that I looked, so no I wasn't banned by Google or any other web search engine for that matter. I did come across a thread that said it is not possible to deny ACL with the PermissionEx element since it would take the parent folder's permission by default so you could just add on to that and not modify it which is the reason I am going the CA route.

Comment: sorry, didn't intend to offend you. However your question seems very same as questions discussed in these threads. They seem to be about adjusting permissions of folders, not users. Please share link to thread with discussion of PermissionEx restrictions. Just curious how bad they are.

Comment: I tried looking for the specific thread but looks like I didn't bookmark it. One of the other threads that I found was:http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg19101.html. Still looking for the thread and will post it here if I find it.

For now I have just gone via the CustomAction route using icacls to set permissions on the folder.